# Redefining `interval` to always be scaled

Tags: macros

I already tried something like this:

```
\let\oldinterval\interval
\renewcommand{\interval}[2]{\oldinterval[scaled]{#1}{#2}}
```

The problem is that I can't use `\interval[open]` anymore.

Is there anyway to fix this?

I would like `\interval[whatever comes here]{a}{b}` te expand to `\oldinterval[whatever comes here, scaled]{a}{b}`.

Comment: I never heard about `\interval` command.

Comment: It's in the interval package, but the answer to this is probably applicable to any command with optional arguments between brackets.`\interval{a}{b}` produces [a,b], but handles open intervals more nicely.

Comment: You need `letltxmacro` package for such optional arg macros

Comment: Could you elaborate that in an answer?

Comment: There, I edited the question a bit to make my intensions clear. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\interval` has one optional and two mandatory arguments.

Using the old definition of such a macro via `\let`, it's better to use Heiko Oberdiek's `letltxmacro` package and `\LetLtxMacro` instead of `\let`

Since the OP wants to have the `scaled` option always in operation, I added it explicitly to the option list as last option, after `#1`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\oldint\interval
\renewcommand{\interval}[3][]{\oldint[#1,scaled]{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}

$\interval{a}{b}$
$\interval[open]{a}{b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Don't. Don't. Don't.*

If you really prefer not to follow the advice, patch the `\interval` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{interval}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\interval}{interval,}{interval,scaled,}{}{}

\begin{document}

$\interval{\dfrac{1}{2}}{b}$
$\interval[open]{\dfrac{1}{2}}{b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you give this advice?... And what's different in this method?

Comment: Because automatic scaling is a bad thing to do. You'll end up adding `scaled=\big` almost as many times as you'd need `scaled`, assuming you want good typography.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not following you yet. Be sure to note that I know exactly nothing about typography.

Comment: @SydKerckhove Let's say you have the interval from (a+b)c to d; then you would prefer `\interval[scaled=\big]{(a+b)c}{d}` rather than `\interval[scaled]{(a+b)c}{d}`. Try it and you'll see: the former will have bigger brackets, the latter won't.

Comment: Dammit, now I will never be satisfied with this solution and have to type `scaled` everywhere. Is there nothing that fixes this automatically?

Comment: @SydKerckhove Why would you type `scaled` everywhere? However, if you think it's good to always have `scaled` (but it isn't), use the patch and, when you need manual scaling, add `scaled=\big` (or `\Big`, `\bigg`, `\Bigg`), which will override `scaled=auto`.

Comment: I don't have to type scaled everywhere, but I will have to scale manually, which is not something I want to do, ideally.